# Complex CSS Navigation Error

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create quite a complex 3D-ish, type navigation buttons without using any images and just CSS! Its a bit of a challenge and my ship has grounded as I have come across a slight problem.

I want my button to fill with orange background color, but it seems only the background around the text is filled? Anyone know why it won't fill all the space.

Thanks!

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="#work">work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#blog">blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#navigation{
    position: relative;
    top:20px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    z-index: 99999;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.07);
    padding:6px 6px 11px 6px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1), 0px 1px 0px #fff;
}
#navigation ul{
    border-radius:3px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px #c6412b;    
}
#navigation ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#navigation ul li a {
    background:#e9573f;
    font-size:22px;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    border-right:1px solid #d44a34;
    border-left:1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255,0.2);
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-bottom:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<li>` elements are setup to be displayed `inline-block`. Therefore, the whitespace between the elements (that is to say, the newline and indentation spaces) render as whitespace between your buttons.

To remove the whitespace between the `<li>`s, remove the newlines:

```
<li><a href="#about">about</a></li><li><a href="#work">work</a></li><li><a href="#blog">blog</a></li><li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
```

To add more space to your buttons, add a padding to your `<li>`s.

Answer (score 1):

Move `background:#e9573f;` from `#navigation ul li a` to `#navigation ul`

Comment: and maybe change the border attributes after that

Answer (score 0):

Here is the CSS to make it work, there's no need for any edits to your html.

Here is the jsfiddle with 10px padding added: http://jsfiddle.net/hDVUE/1/

```
#navigation{
    position: relative;
    top:20px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    z-index: 99999;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.07);
    padding:6px 6px 11px 6px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1), 0px 1px 0px #fff;
}
#navigation ul{
    float:left;
    border-radius:3px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px #c6412b;    
}
#navigation ul li {
    float:left;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#navigation ul li a {
    background:#e9573f;
    font-size:22px;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    border-right:1px solid #d44a34;
    border-left:1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255,0.2);
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-bottom:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}
```